# Infer Date, Hours into datetime64

Tags: python, pandas

Hi every body im new to python. I have  hourly electric data. i have one column for date and one for hour i wanna parse these two into one column and make it index 
This is what my data looks like
[image: This is what my input data looks like]

```
dataset=pd.read_excel('2011-14.xlsx' , sep=';', header=0, 
infer_datetime_format=True, parse_dates={'datetime':[0,1]});
print(dataset.head());
```

After Reading  it in  this way my data looks like 
[image]

How can i convert it into this

2011-01-01 01:00:00  -----
2011-01-01 02:00:00

Comment: Could you please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Images are hard to interpret!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like

```
dataset['datetime'] = [f'{day} {hour:02d}:00:00' for ind, day, hour in dataset[['Date', 'Hour']].itertuples()]
```

Then if you want to change to datetime type

```
dataset = dataset.assign(datetime=df['datetime'].astype('datetime64[ns]'))
```

Comment: That was Very Helpful. Thank You